# Check if current script running directory is a defined folder

Tags: powershell

I got to know that `$PSScriptRoot` returns the current directory where the script is running.
However, using it with an if statement does not work even though the script is running in the same directory as defined.

```
if ($PSScriptRoot -eq "~/.folderwithdotbeforeit/somefolder") {
Write-Host "True"
}
```

Comment: Why would you need this? `$PSScriptRoot` __will be__ the absolute path of the invoked script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$PSScriptRoot is a string, not a Path, so you would need to compare it to a string containing the absolute path you are expecting. In your case, replace ~ by the absolute path of your home directory.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.
But putting the absolute path won't work on other machines because the username will be different for every machine. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You could rebuild the string by using a variable with the user name like $env:USERNAME for instance.